# Every element of a group has finite order

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group, and that the intersection over the non-trivial subgroups of $G$ is non-trivial, i.e., that $$\bigcap_{H<G\atop H\ne \{e\}} H\neq\{e\}.$$ I need to demonstrate that  every element of $G$ has finite order.

I tried showing that if the intersection is trivial, an element of infinite order would be there, but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: So your assumption is $$\bigcap_{H\leq G} H\neq\{e\}?$$

Comment: @Dave yes, Sorry not Very used to LaTeX i wrote It a litlle confuse

Comment: This can never happen though. The trivial group is a subgroup of any group $G$, and since it is the "smallest group", we always have $$\bigcap_{H\leq G} H=\{e\}$$for any $G$.

Comment: @Dave yes, but it is saying there is someone Else there, not only $e$

Comment: But this can never happen. If you're taking the intersection over all subgroups $H$ of a group $G$, then the identity is the only common element in the $H$'s.

Comment: @user528821 - do you mean to take the intersection over NON-TRIVIAL $H$ - i.e., with $H\ne \{e\}$? (going along with Dave's point.)

Comment: @Dave Sorry, forgot an hipotesys, the subgroup of only $e$ is not in the intersection

Comment: @peterag exactly, Sorry guys, It was not explicit in the exercise, Saw It now but still stuck

Comment: @Dave thanks, should i delete the question?